# First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

Are there any cases which the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus would fail?

Comment: General idea is good, but too many words, hiding essential idea. Let $f(x)$ be as in your definition. Then $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ exists and is $0$ for all $x$.  Certainly $F(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$, but $F'(1)=0$ while $f(1)=1$.  (You were asked to prove or disprove $A$ **and** $B$. You have disproved it if you show $B$ fails.)

Comment: Your function is certainly Riemann integrable (only countably many discontinuities). The problem with $F^\prime(1/2)$ is immediate. If $f(x)$ were in addition continuous though, the statement would hold. But isn't $f(1/2) = 1/2$?

Comment: A true theorem never fails.

Answer (score 2):

More simply take $f(x)=\cases{-1,& $0\le x<1/2$\cr  1,& $1/2\le x\le 1$}$. Then  $F'(1/2)$ does not exist (write down the definition of the derivative as a  limit of a difference quotient to see this).

For your example, I don't quite follow your argument, but it seems you've mentioned the necessary ingredients:
$F$ is identically $0$ (this essentially follows from the proof that your $f$ is integrable), so $F'$ is identically $0$. But $F'(x)\ne f(x)$ for any rational number $x$.